# Class for tkinter Button- how to return its value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to create a class to produce a batch of buttons ( 4 ).
I wish to get each button's stats when it's pressed - and when I press each and every one of the buttons, return only the state of last button (4)

`status` was made in order to change the button's state without pressing it (automatic process to simulate button press)

What am I doing wrong?

```
class dev_buttons2(object):
  def __init__(self,master,buts_list):
    self.status=[]
    for i in range(len(buts_list)):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.name=buts_list[i]
        self.c = Checkbutton(master,text=buts_list[i], variable=self.var,
        indicatoron=0,command=self.cb,width=10,height=2)
        self.c.grid(column=i, padx=5,row = 10)
        self.status.append(self.var)

def cb(self):
    #device_chage_state(devices_headers.index(self.name),self.status[i].get() )
    print(self.status[0].get())
    pass
def stat():
    return self.status
```

Comment: You could use `bind` and `<ButtonRelease>` and toggle variables when you press or release buttons

Comment: can it defer between on/off ? isn't there a simplier way to do so ( since I'm new in python )

Comment: You are using `self.var` on every iteration. i don't think that's what you intended to do. same goes for `self.c` and `self.name`.

Comment: @Himal i use `self.var` every iteration in order be able to change each button's state, whitout pressing is. `self.name`- is order to chage title from on to off, and `self.c` was to change its color

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't you use separate variables to store each button's `name` and `variable` ? similar to what you did with `self.status[]` or am i missing something ?

Comment: @Himal , i see ehat you meen. `self.name` is not needed when i have `self.c`, and so is `self.var` since it goes to `self.status`... OK.

Comment: But you are overriding `self.c` on each iteration as well. you'll only have references to your last button. `self.{variable}` will be pointing to the same memory location inside your class. how are you going to store four separate values on `self.var` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149084/discussion-between-guy-d-and-himal).

Comment: @Himal - thanks for the lead- you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Search for an answer yielded the use of `lambda`. 
Using it gives the ability to pass an argument, which is **good**, but I needed to pass **two argumetns**, and lambda` can not do that.

A workaround I used is to pass the arguments `buts_list[i]` ( button's name ) and `var` (button's on/off value) as a **list** using `lambda` to function `cp`which separated them back to 2 arguments in `change_device_state` function.

```
class dev_buttons2(object):
  def __init__(self,master,buts_list):
    self.status=[]
    self.buts=[]
    for i in range(len(buts_list)):
        var = StringVar()
        c = Checkbutton(master,text=buts_list[i], variable=var,
        indicatoron=0,command=lambda arg=[buts_list[i],var]: 
        self.cb(arg),width=10,height=2,onvalue="on",offvalue="off")
        c.grid(column=i, padx=5,row = 10)
        var.set("off")
        self.status.append(var)
        self.buts.append(c)

  def cb(self,but):
    device_chage_state(devices_headers.index(but[0]),but[1].get())
```